# How to pull the latest or minimum start date, based on the break-up in continuation of the start date and end date of the records using SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql

Please help me to create a sql query to pull the minimum or latest startdate of the employees using below conditions.

1. if there is no break-up in the continuity of start and end date of the records, pass the minimum start date.
2. if there is a break-up within 30 days between end and start date of previous and current records, pass the minimum start date
3. if the break-up is more than 30 days between end and start date of previous and current records, pass the latest start date.

Example:
Below is the data table

```
EmpID   ProdID  HireStartDt HireEndDate
98765   X123    08/01/2020  12/31/2020
98765   X123    01/01/2021  12/31/2021
98765   X123    01/01/2022  12/31/2022
43567   X123    01/01/2021  12/31/2021
43567   X123    01/29/2022  12/31/2022
65427   X123    05/06/2021  08/28/2021
65427   X123    03/01/2022  12/31/2022
```

For EmpID : 98765, we need pass the minimum start date as '08/01/2020' as there is no break-up in the continuation of startDt and End Dt between the records.

For EmpID : 43567, we need pass the minimum start date as '01/01/2021' because the break-up is less than 30 days between EndDt of previous record and startDt of current record.

For EmpID : 65427, we need pass the latest start date as '03/01/2022' because the break-up is greater than 30 days between EndDt of previous record and startDt of current record.

Expected Result:

```
EmpID   ProdID  HireStartDt HireEndDate
98765   X123    08/01/2020  12/31/2020
43567   X123    01/01/2021  12/31/2021
65427   X123    03/01/2022  12/31/2022
```

Please help me !!

Thanks
Gopal

Comment: I am not clear what should happen where there are multiple entries but some are continuous and some not eg (1,   'X123'  , '08/01/2020','10/31/2020'),
(1,   'X123'  ,  '01/01/2021','12/31/2021'),
(1,   'X123'  ,  '01/01/2022', '12/31/2022');

Comment: For the continuous records we need to pass the minimum start date, whereas for discontinuing records we need to check date difference between the previous record end date and start date of the current record, if the difference is less than 30 days then we can pass the minimum start date else we need to pass the latest start date. Hope it helps..

Comment: Your last comment just repeats the question and doen't help. In your sample you have 2 cases with discontinuous data but only 2 rows in my example the first and second are discontinuous but 2 and third are not

Comment: Are you working with MySQL or SQL Server? I added an answer for SQL Server's Transact-SQL (T-SQL) syntax since there was a tsql tag. I then realized you have a MySQL tag, so I converted the code to MySQL. However, MySQL and T-SQL are semantically different so those tags should not be used together.

Answer (score 0):

In your example output, you show the end date that is on the same record as the chosen start date. However, it seems like you would actually want the latest end date, which are all 12/31/2022. If that is correct, the below code should work for you.

If, however, the end date needs to be from the same record as the chosen start date, this code will not produce that result. That query is equally simple to produce though if needed.

The query output is given below the code.

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS EmployeeCoverage;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE EmployeeCoverage
(
    EmpID INT
    , ProdID VARCHAR(4)
    , HireStartDt DATE
    , HireEndDt DATE
);

INSERT INTO EmployeeCoverage
    (EmpID, ProdID, HireStartDt, HireEndDt)
VALUES
    (98765, 'X123', '2020-08-01', '2020-12-31'),
    (98765, 'X123', '2021-01-01', '2021-12-31'),
    (98765, 'X123', '2022-01-01', '2022-12-31'),
    (43567, 'X123', '2021-01-01', '2021-12-31'),
    (43567, 'X123', '2022-01-29', '2022-12-31'),
    (65427, 'X123', '2021-05-06', '2021-08-28'),
    (65427, 'X123', '2022-03-01', '2022-12-31');

SELECT * FROM EmployeeCoverage;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS EmployeeCoverageGaps;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE EmployeeCoverageGaps
(
    EmpID INT
    , ProdID VARCHAR(4)
    , HireStartDt DATE
    , HireEndDt DATE
    , GapDays INT -- Possibly SMALLINT
);

INSERT INTO EmployeeCoverageGaps
    (EmpID, ProdID, HireStartDt, HireEndDt, GapDays)
SELECT
    EmpID, ProdID, HireStartDt, HireEndDt
    -- Get the days between the current end date and the next start date
    , COALESCE(DATEDIFF(
        LEAD(HireStartDt) OVER
            (PARTITION BY EmpID, ProdID ORDER BY HireStartDt)
        , HireEndDt), 0) AS GapDays
FROM
    EmployeeCoverage;

SELECT * FROM EmployeeCoverageGaps;

SELECT
    EmpID
    , ProdID
    , MIN(HireStartDt) AS HireStartDt
    , MAX(HireEndDt) AS HireEndDt
FROM EmployeeCoverageGaps
WHERE GapDays < 30 -- Remove start/end ranges with gaps more than 30 days
GROUP BY EmpID, ProdID;
```

| EmpID | ProdID | HireStartDt | HireEndDt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 43567 | X123 | 2021-01-01 | 2022-12-31 |
| 65427 | X123 | 2022-03-01 | 2022-12-31 |
| 98765 | X123 | 2020-08-01 | 2022-12-31 |